# Templated operator overload trick

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

Is there a way to by using some metaprogramming trick make situation like this works:

```
int* get();//this fnc returns pointer to int OR nullptr
int k = 1;
//this is the operator which is supposed to compare value and pointer
template<class T>
bool operator!=(const T& left, const T* right)
{
    if (right)
    {
        return left != *right;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


//And this is the code fragment which interests me most  
if (k != get())
{
    ///

}
```

The crux is that I would like NOT TO change this line k != get() and yet for some reason my operator!= seems not to work. What's the problem?

Comment: Not everything that uses templates is metaprogramming

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Modifying the usual meaning of the inequality operator is generally discouraged, think that people (including you) will need to read and understand your code, so you should avoid "weird" things (such as writing a binary operator that dereferences only one of its operand). BTW, if you don't want to change the line `k != get()`, you can perhaps change `get` so that it returns a reference: `int & get();`.

Comment: @Luc yes I do agree with what you're saying, and in general I do avoid such things. This is somewhat 'special' situation and believe me if you'd see whole code you'd say that it's good design. As for get, no, it has to return *. Thanks.

Comment: Just write a named function and be done with it.

Comment: STL has some numeric and logical functions built-in. See the numeric library (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/). Also if you have Boost installed checkout the Boost Operators library (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/utility/operators.htm).

Comment: If (x != y) is false then we can usually assume that x == y. If you write operators that break these usual rules, you're making a bad use of overloaded operators.

Comment: @unkulunku yep, but that's why the title, I'd hope that by using some metaprogramming this can be done.

Comment: @smallB all your title are belong to us

Comment: @smallB http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fvTxv46ano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in other answers that you cannot have `operator !=` for non userdefined types like `int`, `char` and so on.

One option is to wrap `int` inside your user defined `struct` and achieve the goal.

```
struct Int
{
  int i;
  // define all the necessary operators/constructor who deal with 'int'
  Int(int x) : i(x) {}
  bool operator != (const int* right)
  {
    return (right)? (i != *right) : false;
  }
};
```

Now declare

```
Int k = 1;
```

Comment: I think it's illogical that if `right == NULL` then `return false`. I think the OP meant `return true`

Comment: @Armen, I have just simplified the OP's condition in my code. I think it's not of concern here. Also, if `right == NULL` then `right` is not comparable to `i`; so `return false;` is proper.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice. I'll move my comment to the question instead :)

Answer (score 6):

You can only overload operators with at least one user-defined type as an argument. Neither `int` nor `int*` are user-defined types.

Answer (score 3):

You can't overload operators for builtin types.